# Connecting to MSSQL from Ruby on Rails from Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, linux, sql-server-2008, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The title sums up the whole problem.

To use RoR, I was suggested to use Linux, so I got a VirtualBox and got Ubuntu 13 on it, installed RVM and RoR and now I'm pretty stuck.

I need to access the MSSQL from Ruby from inside the Ubuntu, and I don't have a single clue.
A question of relevance was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176268/connecting-to-an-mssql-database-from-a-ruby-on-rails-application-running-on-ubun), but the answer links seemed to have expired, and the one that isn't, I can't make out a method of how to do it.

Any approach suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872264/correct-mysql-configuration-for-ruby-on-rails-database-yml-file also get mysql client with yum install mysql

Comment: @bapusethi The question is about Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL

Comment: http://www.thesatya.com/blog/2010/02/rails_sybase_solved.html My blog, old post, sybase, may work for mssql too as it involves JDBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple if you use freetds. Install freetds library. Its available in ubuntu repository.

sudo apt-get install freetds

Then follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTds)